# Someone has integrated Play Integrity API with a React Native App?

Tags: android, react-native, security, google-play, integrity

I want to mitigate File Intregrity Check Vulnerability from my Android App, I've checked all documentation about [Google Play Integrity](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/overview) and is done almost all the steps but don't know how to integrate this API to my React Native Android App.

Somebody can help me with this implementation... thanks a lot!

I already have enabled the configuration from Play Console and place a new service in my Google Cloud. What's next?